# Unable to resolve address for Kubernetes service

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

I have installed Kafka `single-node` using [Confluent](https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kubernetes-examples/blob/master/quickstart-deploy/confluent-platform-singlenode.yaml). There is an error in `Kafka` pod :

```
[WARN] 2022-04-26 14:29:47,008 [main-SendThread(zookeeper.confluent.svc.cluster.local:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn run - Session 0x0 for sever zookeeper.confluent.svc.cluster.local:2181, Closing socket connection. Attempting reconnect except it is a SessionExpiredException.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to canonicalize address zookeeper.confluent.svc.cluster.local:2181 because it's not resolvable
        at org.apache.zookeeper.SaslServerPrincipal.getServerPrincipal(SaslServerPrincipal.java:78)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.SaslServerPrincipal.getServerPrincipal(SaslServerPrincipal.java:41)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.startConnect(ClientCnxn.java:1161)
        at org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn$SendThread.run(ClientCnxn.java:1210)
[INFO] 2022-04-26 14:29:47,273 [main] kafka.zookeeper.ZooKeeperClient info - [ZooKeeperClient Kafka server] Closing.
[ERROR] 2022-04-26 14:29:48,112 [main-SendThread(zookeeper.confluent.svc.cluster.local:2181)] org.apache.zookeeper.client.StaticHostProvider resolve - Unable to resolve address: zookeeper.confluent.svc.cluster.local:2181
java.net.UnknownHostException: zookeeper.confluent.svc.cluster.local
```

Error messages :

```
Unable to canonicalize address zookeeper.confluent.svc.cluster.local:2181 because it's not resolvable
Unable to resolve address: zookeeper.confluent.svc.cluster.local:2181
```

I checked my `zookeper` ... it's good and works without a problem. Also, check DNS using `dnsutils` :

```sh
$ kubectl -n default exec -it dnsutils -- nslookup zookeeper.confluent.svc.cluster.local

Server:         10.96.0.10
Address:        10.96.0.10#53

Name:   zookeeper.confluent.svc.cluster.local
Address: 192.168.0.111
```

What can I do? Is this a k8s related problem?

Comment: It sure does look like `zookeeper.confluent.svc.cluster.local:2181` is being used where it expects an **address**, so try removing the :2181

Comment: Outside of that, you'd also want to exec into the offending pod, not some random `dnsutils` one -- if the kafka pod is misconfigured, asking some other pod's opinion won't help you troubleshoot this offtopic question

Comment: I tried with another pod ( curl - nc ) in the same namespace/environment ... that pod cannot access too @mdaniel. Maybe it's a CNI problem .... I'm try reconfigure cluster using Flannel

Comment: The Strimzi Kafka operator has very clear networking documentation, by the way. The Confluent Operator will cost money if you scale beyond one broker.

Answer (score 0):

This happens with me, but on docker-compose project

finally, I found that no space left on server causes this issue.
clean some spaces and it worked.